# Export To Text file with Text Align

Tags: c#

how can i export set of data in SQL or Access to text file with text align ?
there is a AS400 system. witch employees have to enter Purchase orders one by one.
(customers send their Purchase orders by Excel)
i created a tool using C# to import excel and import to a access DB
and i want to know how to export to a text file with correct text length.(so i can import to the System Direcly)
this is the format i want

Name| Width|Type|Alignment|Remark

NO|10|  N|   Right left |  pad with blank

Type|2|      C|    Left|Default 'SO'

Company|5|   C|  Left|  Default Blank

Depot Code|12| C|Right| left pad with blank

Customer Code|9|N| Right|left pad with blank

Out put :--
  40000013SO              211     5031JHX400B                  PKPK             500 041013

Comment: OMG run, `witch` employees!

Comment: when i export i does't export as the database align.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this just using `string.Format()`. Take a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx. If is possible to specify the width of a field and its text alignment, thus allowing you to lay out the fields as per your requirements.